# Extracting gallery images in Wordpress 3.5 on index.php

Tags: images, gallery, the-content, read-more

I'm trying to add a slider on my front blog page for every gallery post, but I have some trouble extracting the images from the post gallery, using the following code:

```
$post_content = get_the_content();
preg_match('/\[gallery.*ids=.(.*).\]/', $post_content, $ids);
$array_id = explode(",", $ids[1]);
```

The problem is that each gallery post consists of paragraph with text, "read more" break and a gallery after the break and thus **get_the_content()** skips the images because they are after the break. How can I make it get the whole content, regardless of breaks?

I use "read more" because I want short description about the gallery post before clicking on it to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_the_content` is a template tag and would only work reliably inside a Loop. That means that you should also be able to use the `$post` global instead.

```
global $post; // may not be necessary unless you have scope issues
              // for example, this is inside a function
$post_content = $post->post_content;
preg_match('/\[gallery.*ids=.(.*).\]/', $post_content, $ids);
$array_id = explode(",", $ids[1]);
```

You can then use [`wp_get_attachment_image`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image) to actually get the images.

```
foreach ($array_ids as $id) {
  echo  wp_get_attachment_image($id);
}
```

Comment: Hi again, after using this code, can you please help me find a way to get all the images by their ID using the values in `$array_id` ?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image